# columns wrap jsPDF auto-table not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

By looking at many examples online, it seems straightforward, but I am not able to wrap my columns (line break). I am not able to change the versions due to some internal conflicts where the code eventually goes. what I am doing wrong ? I used to make an object and pass it as a parameter to doc.autotable() but that seems not rendering to the pdf, so I am doing the styling "inline" in the parameter like the example below. I want to wrap name and country to next lines, like one would do to a regular table. these data all comes from the back end so, I want to check for this before becomes a problem.

it looks like this now [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.60/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.15/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.15/jspdf.plugin.autotable.src.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="generatePdf()">Generate pdf</button>


    <script>
        function generatePdf() {

            var columns = [{
                title: "ID",
                dataKey: "id"
            },
            {
                title: "Name",
                dataKey: "name"
            },
            {
                title: "Country",
                dataKey: "country"
            },
            ];
            var rows = [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ShawNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "TanzaniaNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "NelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "KazakhstanNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "GarciaNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "MadagascarNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
            },
            ];


            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

            var header = function (data) {
                doc.setFontSize(18);
                doc.setTextColor(40);
                doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                doc.text("Testing Report", data.settings.margin.left, 50);
            };

            doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {styles: {
                overflow: 'linebreak',
                columnWidth: 'wrap'
            },
                columnStyles: {
                    2: { columnWidth: 'auto' }
                }
                
            });

            doc.save("table.pdf");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following,

```
columnStyles: { name: { columnWidth: 'auto' }, country: { columnWidth: 'auto' } }
```

The name and country column will work

Answer (score 0):

you can test:

```
      <script>
          function generatePdf() {
            const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
      
            const columns = [{
              title: "ID",
              dataKey: "id"
            },
              {
                title: "Name",
                dataKey: "name"
              },
              {
                title: "Country",
                dataKey: "country"
              },
            ];
            const rows = [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ShawNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "TanzaniaNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "NelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "KazakhstanNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "GarciaNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson",
                "country": "MadagascarNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelsonNelson"
              }
            ];
            const header = function (data) {
              doc.setFontSize(18);
              doc.setTextColor(40);
              doc.text("Testing Report", data.settings.margin.left, 20);
            };
            doc.autoTable({
              body: [...rows],
              columns: [...columns],
              startY: 40,
              styles: {
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                overflow: 'linebreak',
                columnWidth: 'auto'
              },
              columnStyles: {
                country: {columnWidth: 'wrap'}
              },
              didDrawPage: header
            });
            doc.save('Test.pdf');
          }
      </script>
```